# Wordpress plugin Countdown Timer (ABT) integrate in theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is the plugin: http://www.atlanticbt.com/blog/countdown-timer-in-wordpress/ I want to integrate it in my theme using the functions here described (in the link) but i don't know how to do. This is the code (it displays 3 posts from a category) where i want to integrate it:

```
<?php 
  $thumbnails = get_posts('numberposts=3&cat=3');
  foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
        echo '<div class="contest-home"><a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'medium',  array('class'=> "blur") );
        echo '</a>';
    echo '<h2><center>' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '</center></h2>';
    echo get_post_meta($thumbnail->ID, "RiassuntoHome", true);
    echo '<p><b>Giorni restanti:</b> Here it should be the function';
    echo '<br><b>Premio: </b>'. get_post_meta($thumbnail->ID, "Montepremi", true) . '';
    echo '</p><center><a class="btn-contest-home" href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '">Invia la Tua Idea</a></center></div>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use a short code where you wants to display the timer short code looks like [countdown_timer]

here is the like for more parameters in short code http://s.wordpress.org/plugins/countdown-timer-abt/screenshot-2.png?r=819719

if you like to use this short in a php files use like this

Comment: sorry by mistake yes i forget, like this <?php echo do_shortcode("[countdown_timer]") ?>

Comment: i have 2 problems:
- the first one is that for each post it gets the same date (that of the first post) i think this is caused by the fact that in your code you hadn't added something that say to wp to ask for the shortcode in that post.
- the second one is less important, the code that this string produces is not raw text but there are also classes. Maybe you can tell me how to obtain only the date as text. 
Thank you very much for the help given.

Comment: sorry i didn't get can you please send a screen shot where is the problem or give a url of the site so i can check it out.